# How I can make category url

Tags: routing

I tried to make mysite.com/category page where I want to see list of categories.
How to show list of categories I know.
I can not make a link 'category'.
I have tried to call this file 'archive-category.php', but site response 404.
If I tried to call this file 'category.php' , then site route url mysite.com/category/info through template category.php, but url /category  return me again 404.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be running into duplicate slugs. In a basic install I tried to create a Page with the URL `example.com/category/` and that worked fine. My permalinks are set to `example.com/category/categoryname/` for each individual category, and `example.com/year/post-name/` for individual posts.

You could either try changing your permalinks and removing `/category/` from them if it is there, or try combing through your database to figure out where you have a `category` slug. If you have uploaded a media file (jpg, etc.) that can take up a slug, as can all other post types like Post, Page, or custom post types. If WP already has one item with the slug `category` that is why it isn't allowing you to create any other item (of any kind) with the same slug. It wouldn't know which one to use.

You can always try visiting `example.com/category/` to figure out whether there really is something at that URL. If not, I would try changing permalinks to see whether that resolves the issue.

Once you get that sorted, you'll want to create a Page Template - `archive-category.php` is used to display individual Categories. You can either make a file called `page-category.php` and it will automatically apply to your Page with slug "category," or you can make a file called `tpl-category-listing.php` then apply it in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I create new page with slug category,and in the template folder file page-category.php, 
and it all worked.
Thank you all for your help.